# Get JSON file from itunes lookup using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, itunes, lookup

I'm trying to get the info inside the JSON file that itunes lookup returns, but my code doesn't work. 
If I save file that this url returns, which would be a .js file, and upload it to my server and pass in the url of that file it works, but when I'm trying to read file directly from itunes it doesn't.

Please help me out if you have any clues.

Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     $.getJSON( "http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=600172326", function(data) {

             var icon = document.getElementById("WallpaperIcon");
             var description = document.getElementById("WallpaperDescription");

             icon.src = data.results[0].artworkUrl100;
             description.innerHTML = data.results[0].description;
      });

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iTunes probably doesn't have CORS enabled, so you can't make an Ajax request to the service. However, luckily for you it seems to support [**JSONP**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP):

```
$.getJSON('http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=600172326&callback=?', ...);
```

More about `$.getJSON` and JSONP: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/#jsonp

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tuf9tdgL/)

Comment: I did some similar work using PHP CURL and spoofing the user agent

Comment: Hello DeFeNdog,
I'm also developing a WP plguin and need iTunes data to lookup.
I need your help doing it using PHP CURL. 
Would you please help me posting your code and instructions?
It'd be really helpful.
Thanks