# Output of more than one screenshots from json-file (e.g. itunes search api)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How can i insert a loop and view for one or more jpg screenshot-urls from json-variable "screenshotUrls"?

```js
$.getJSON("https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=343200656&callback=?", function (data) {
var icon =   document.getElementById("icon");
var name =   document.getElementById("name");
var description =  document.getElementById("description");

icon.src =   data.results[0].artworkUrl100;
name.innerHTML =  data.results[0].trackName;
description.innerHTML = data.results[0].description;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="appicon"><img id="icon"></div>
<h3 id="name">.</h3>
<p id="description">.</p>
```

Comment: Before looking into the issue, why did you tag this post IOS? Is there anything specific IOS about it? (Also, you should tag it JQUERY.)

Answer (score 0):

When I call that URL ( https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=343200656&callback=? <-- make sure to copy that ? too, becuase SO removes it from the hyperlink, probably because it is invalid. BUT it is included in the original URL in the script... ) , this is the response:

```
{
 "errorMessage":"Invalid value(s) for key(s): [callback]",
 "queryParameters":{"output":"json", "callback":"A javascript function to handle your search results", "country":"ISO-2A country code", "limit":"The number of search results to return", "term":"A search string", "lang":"ISO-2A language code"}
}
```

If I were you, I would start there before looking any further.

In the meantime (We are having a little discussion about the trailing ? after the callback=? in the original URL. That gives an error for me). I use the one without the last ? in the URL. (It is also invalid to put two ? in the url)

**How to use the response?**

Symply do something like this:

```
var myResp = data;
```

Next use myResp as an object with properties (name/value paisr)

For example:

```
myResp.resultCount <-- will return 1
```

The response looks like the following to me:

```
{
 "resultCount":1,
 "results": [
{
"screenshotUrls":["http://a4.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple5/v4/37/00/46/37004662-657e-1964-a0dd-1266ddf6e096/screen320x320.jpeg", "http://a4.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple69/v4/49/16/ba/4916ba99-3c0f-1b18-b873-a509e8b7a5e3/screen320x320.jpeg", "http://a2.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple7/v4/4e/0b/56/4e0b56da-8dcd-8be2-d07a-64631ff45295/screen320x320.jpeg", "http://a4.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple7/v4/e6/16/94/e6169414-818b-a86c-f37c-4bad6a9f1f6f/screen320x320.jpeg", "http://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple69/v4/9b/a1/6f/9ba16f4f-99bd-36a2-fccd-c3edfa181ff3/screen320x320.jpeg"], "ipadScreenshotUrls":[], "artworkUrl512":"http://is3.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple5/v4/80/28/4c/80284c71-3c6b-470c-00a3-b7129e4ab814/source/512x512bb.jpg", "artistViewUrl":"https://itunes.apple.com/us/developer/rovio-entertainment-ltd/id298910979?uo=4", "artworkUrl60":"http://is3.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple5/v4/80/28/4c/80284c71-3c6b-470c-00a3-b7129e4ab814/source/60x60bb.jpg", "artworkUrl100":"http://is3.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple5/v4/80/28/4c/80284c71-3c6b-470c-00a3-b7129e4ab814/source/100x100bb.jpg", "isGameCenterEnabled":true, "kind":"software", "features":["gameCenter"], 
"supportedDevices":["iPhone-3GS", "iPhone4", "iPodTouchFourthGen", "iPad2Wifi", "iPad23G", "iPhone4S", "iPadThirdGen", "iPadThirdGen4G", "iPhone5", "iPodTouchFifthGen", "iPadFourthGen", "iPadFourthGen4G", "iPadMini", "iPadMini4G", "iPhone5c", "iPhone5s", "iPhone6", "iPhone6Plus", "iPodTouchSixthGen"], "advisories":[], "languageCodesISO2A":["EN", "FR", "DE", "IT", "JA", "PT", "RU", "ZH", "ES", "ZH"], "fileSizeBytes":"71674372", "sellerUrl":"http://www.angrybirds.com/", "averageUserRatingForCurrentVersion":4.0, "userRatingCountForCurrentVersion":1195, "trackContentRating":"4+", "trackCensoredName":"Angry Birds", "trackViewUrl":"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/angry-birds/id343200656?mt=8&uo=4", "contentAdvisoryRating":"4+", "minimumOsVersion":"6.0", "formattedPrice":"$0.99", "currency":"USD", "wrapperType":"software", "version":"6.0.1", "artistId":298910979, "artistName":"Rovio Entertainment Ltd", "genres":["Games", "Arcade", "Entertainment", "Action"], "price":0.99, 
"description":"Use the unique powers of the Angry Birds to destroy the greedy pigs' defenses!\u2028\u2028\n\nThe survival of the Angry Birds is at stake. Dish out revenge on the greedy pigs who stole their eggs. Use the unique powers of each bird to destroy the pigs’ defenses. Angry Birds features challenging physics-based gameplay and hours of replay value. Each level requires logic, skill and force to solve.\u2028\u2028\n\nIf you get stuck in the game, you can purchase the Mighty Eagle! Mighty Eagle is a one-time in-app purchase in Angry Birds that gives unlimited use. This phenomenal creature will soar from the skies to wreak havoc and smash the pesky pigs into oblivion. There’s just one catch: you can only use the aid of Mighty Eagle to pass a level once per hour. Mighty Eagle also includes all new gameplay goals and achievements!\u2028\u2028\n\nIn addition to the Mighty Eagle, Angry Birds now has power-ups! Boost your birds’ abilities and three-star levels to unlock secret content! Angry Birds now has the following amazing power-ups: Sling Scope for laser targeting, King Sling for maximum flinging power, Super Seeds to supersize your birds, and Birdquake to shake pigs’ defenses to the ground!\u2028\u2028\n\nHAVING TROUBLE? Head over to https://support.rovio.com where you can browse FAQs or submit a request to our support flock!\n\n#1 IPHONE PAID APP in US, UK, Canada, Italy, Germany, Russia, Sweden, Denmark, Finland, Singapore, Poland, France, Netherlands, Malta, Greece, Austria, Australia, Turkey, UAE, Saudi Arabia, Israel, Belgium, Norway, Hungary, Malaysia, Luxembourg, Portugal, Czech Republic, Spain, Ireland, Romania, New Zealand, Latvia, Lithuania, Estonia, Nicaragua, Kazakhstan, Argentina, Bulgaria, Slovakia, Slovenia, Mauritius, Chile, Hong Kong, Pakistan, Taiwan, Colombia, Indonesia, Thailand, India, Kenya, Macedonia, Croatia, Macau, Paraguay, Peru, Armenia, Philippines, Vietnam, Jordan and Kuwait. \u2028\u2028\n\n#1 IPHONE PAID GAME in more countries than we can count!\n\nTerms of Use: http://www.rovio.com/eula\u2028\nPrivacy Policy: http://www.rovio.com/privacy\u2028\n\nThis application may require internet connectivity and subsequent data transfer charges may apply.\n\n\nImportant Message for Parents\n\nThis game may include:\n- Direct links to social networking websites that are intended for an audience over the age of 13.\n- Direct links to the internet that can take players away from the game with the potential to browse any web page.\n- Advertising of Rovio products and also products from select partners.\n- The option to make in-app purchases. The bill payer should always be consulted beforehand.", "trackName":"Angry Birds", "trackId":343200656, "bundleId":"com.clickgamer.AngryBirds", "releaseDate":"2009-12-11T08:00:00Z", "primaryGenreName":"Games", "isVppDeviceBasedLicensingEnabled":true, "currentVersionReleaseDate":"2015-12-11T08:02:04Z", "releaseNotes":"The #1 App of all time turns 6!\nJoin the celebration in 15 all-new levels in the BirdDay episode!", "sellerName":"Rovio Entertainment Ltd", "primaryGenreId":6014, "genreIds":["6014", "7003", "6016", "7001"], "averageUserRating":4.5, "userRatingCount":822974}]
}
```

Now, how do you want to proceed?

EDIT: You want all screenshot url.

You can go there with something like:

```
myResp.results[0].screenshotUrls <-- will be an array.
```

I haven't checked the code, but just inspect the JSON response, and try to go to the desired element, paying attention to the craziness of the response, that is a mix of object and array notation.

Comment: the script works for me, no errors (also in snippet browser). i only want to know how i can insert a loop for the screenshots. thx!

Comment: If you put https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=343200656&callback=? in your browser, do you get a JSON response that is valid?

Comment: yes, i get a beautiful valid json file (rfc 4627)!?

Comment: Are you sure you have that trailing ? after callback= ?????? (My link is screwed up SO, use the one you posted in your own code)

Comment: okay, i know now what you mean. but can you see the angry birds icon and that the script is working? look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25876331/get-json-file-from-itunes-lookup-using-javascript)

Comment: thanks for your time and explanation. but, i already have the array with "data.results[0].screenshotUrls;" like the other arrays (eg "data.results[0].trackName;") in my first post. i don´t know how i should work with this array to bring it to html. i think i need a loop or something, i don´t know. therefore i asked "How can i insert a loop and view for one or more jpg screenshot-urls....".

Comment: You will have to loop over the array, get the urls to the images, and then decide where to put them. You will need DOM manipulation functions, eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932759/dom-appendchild-to-insert-images